# writing a TCP listener with an object as a param

Tags: c#, tcp, streamreader, streamwriter

I understand how to send an object through a TCP connection in C#; I'm using `StreamWriter`.

How can I recieve this object from the other side?

I have tried `StreamReader` but it doesn't contain a parameter of type `object`.

How can this be done?

Comment: You should read some docs about `Serialization`,  `XmlSerializer` `BinaryFormatter` `SoapFormatter` `DataContractSerializer` `JavaScriptSerializer` etc

Comment: StreamReader/Writer are for text. If you're not writing text, why do you write text?

Comment: Well, here is what I want to do:
I want to send an array of Images:
Image[] ImgArr = new ImgArr[2];
object Obj = (object) ImgArr;

I want to send 'Obj' and recieve it at client side as another object to use the inside images...

Comment: I serialized an array of objects containing 2 array of bytes for two images, it worked and I received both images successfully, but the feed is too slow...

Answer (score 1):

IMO best solution is to use `BinaryReader` to read from the stream. Moreover you should write the stream using `BinaryWriter` class.

If your object is not one of basic types then you have to serialize before sending it through TCP connection.

Comment: Well, here is what I want to do: I want to send an array of Images: Image[] ImgArr = new ImgArr[2]; object Obj = (object) ImgArr; I want to send 'Obj' and recieve it at client side as another object to use the inside images...

Comment: You have to serialize your object using BinaryFormatter and deserialize it on another side: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I can really recommend using [ProtoBuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) to transform your objects to/from bytes that you can send over the network (i.e. serialization). It's all around much better than the built-in binary serializers (speed, versioning).

It also has friendly helpers for including a length/size prefix to the data written, which is helpful when you need to read the data on the receiving side.

The following is a helper class I've used to do the serialization and network communication, once the connection has been established:

```
public class Messenger
{
    private readonly TcpClient client;

    private readonly NetworkStream stream;

    public IPEndPoint RemoteEndPoint { get { return (IPEndPoint) client.Client.RemoteEndPoint; } }

    public Messenger( TcpClient client )
    {
        this.client = client;
        stream = client.GetStream();
    }

    #region Send and Receive
    public TResponse SendReceive<TRequest, TResponse>( TRequest request ) where TRequest : Message where TResponse : Message
    {
        Send( request );
        return Receive<TResponse>();
    }

    public void Send<TRequest>( TRequest request ) where TRequest : Message
    {
        using( var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix( ms, request, PrefixStyle.Fixed32 );
            stream.Write( ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int) ms.Length );
            stream.Flush();
        }
    }

    public TResponse Receive<TResponse>() where TResponse : Message
    {
        try
        {
            return GetMessage<TResponse>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is IOException || ex is InvalidOperationException)
            {
                stream.Dispose();
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Helpers
    private TMessage GetMessage<TMessage>() where TMessage : Message
    {
        int messageLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(GetBytes(stream, 4), 0);
        byte[] data = GetBytes(stream, messageLength);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            return Serializer.Deserialize<TMessage>(ms);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] GetBytes(NetworkStream stream, int length)
    {
        int bytesRequired = length;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        var bytes = new byte[length];
        do
        {
            while( !stream.DataAvailable )
                Thread.Sleep( 100 );                    
            int read = stream.Read(bytes, bytesRead, bytesRequired);
            bytesRequired -= read;
            bytesRead += read;
        }
        while (bytesRequired > 0);
        return bytes;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Note: the Serializer class is from the ProtoBuf library.

Comment: Well, here is what I want to do: I want to send an array of Images: Image[] ImgArr = new ImgArr[2]; object Obj = (object) ImgArr; I want to send 'Obj' and recieve it at client side as another object to use the inside images...

Comment: Then create a class with an Images property (of type Image[]), decorate it with the required ProtoBuf attributes (study the docs for help on this, or search StackOverflow), and use the Send method to have it transmitted (and Receive on the receiving side, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want or can't use [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx), you will have to deserialize the object yoursekf

Modified example from msdn for Binary Formatter:

Let's say you have you model:

```
[Serializable] //you could also make the class implement ISerializable
class SomeModel
{
    public String Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

you have your NetworkStream:

```
NetworkStream ns;
```

basic example of how you'd do the serialization part:

```
void Serialize() 
{
    SomeModel myModel = new SomeModel()
    {
        Name = "mooo"
    };

    // Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it to serialize the data to the stream.
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    try 
    {
        formatter.Serialize(ns, myModel);
    }
    catch (SerializationException e) 
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

and as for deserializing

```
void Deserialize() 
{
    SomeModel myModel;
    try 
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        // Deserialize the object from the stream and 
        // assign the reference to the local variable.
        myModel = (SomeModel) formatter.Deserialize(ns);
    }
    catch (SerializationException e) 
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

There's one thing you have to take care off.
You have to know when you deserialize, you can't just throw the stream in it and get something back, you'll have to know that what you are going to read is in fact a serialized SomeModel-class.
I don't know how your code looks like so I don't know if this is an issue or not and if it is how to avoid it.

Anyway, your second choice would be to use a BinaryReader.
You'd have to create an instance of you object, and read the data manually.

```
using(BinaryWriter writer =
    new BinaryWriter(ns))
{
    binWriter.Write(myModel.Name);
}
```

reading:

```
 using(BinaryReader reader =
        new BinaryReader(ns))
 {
    try
    {
        SomeModel myModel = new SomeModel();

        myModel.Name = binReader.ReadString();
    }

    // If the end of the stream is reached before reading
    // the four data values, ignore the error and use the
    // default settings for the remaining values.
    catch(EndOfStreamException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} caught and ignored. " +
            "Using default values.", e.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, here is what I want to do: I want to send an array of Images: Image[] ImgArr = new ImgArr[2]; object Obj = (object) ImgArr; I want to send 'Obj' and recieve it at client side as another object to use the inside images...